# How to convert comma separated parameters to rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, function, csv

In my function I used **`IN`** key word with **`where`**   I have one parameter value

e.g.:

```
CASE- 1
 '1,8,9' or

CASE- 2
 '9,8,7,4,5'   or

CASE- 3
 '9,8'
```

now I get pass first '1,8,9' then result set Comes basis on only 1 ,

same as second case '9,8,7,4,5' then result set comes basis on only 9 ,

I think 'where' condition with 'IN' keyword consider only first ID

Now my question is what should I do for comma separated to rows values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement for `in` when things are stored in a list is `find_in_set()`:

```
where find_in_set(col, '1,2,3') > 0
```

Note that this cannot take advantage of an index, so it is not recommended on larger tables.  You should put the list into the SQL, either as an `in` or as a subquery, to make use of indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give the `IN()` clause **seperate** values and not a **single one** that has a list in it. This would work:

```
where some_column in ('9','8','7','4','5' )
```

In MySQL you can use the [`FIELD()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field) instead:

```
where field(some_column, '9,8,7,4,5') > 0
```

Comment: Please be more specific. What did you try, what error do you get and what output do ou expect? Can you add that to your question?