# How to convert comma separated string value into rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, recursive-query

I have one column in MySQL which is return me comma separated value , I want to convert that column in to rows.

Better answer then [How to convert comma separated parameters to rows in mysql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22732151/how-to-convert-comma-separated-parameters-to-rows-in-mysql)

`select value from table limit 1`

response

| value |
| --- |
| honda,activa,pleasure,car |

I want this value to row like

| value |
| --- |
| honda |
| activa |
| pleasure |
| car |

Comment: 8.0.29 Mysql Version

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```sql
CREATE TABLE response (id INT, value TEXT)
SELECT 1 id, 'honda,activa,pleasure,car' value;
```

```sql
SELECT response.id, jsontable.value
FROM response
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CONCAT('["', REPLACE(value, ',', '","'), '"]'),
                      '$[*]' COLUMNS (value TEXT PATH '$')) jsontable;
```

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | honda |
| 1 | activa |
| 1 | pleasure |
| 1 | car |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mhIMu2rw)

PS. The query assumes that the value does not contain duoble quotes. If they are present then they must be quoted. See https://dbfiddle.uk/HUmPZEo1

Comment: This query won't work if data is not regular, it will throw JSON error

Comment: @HarikrushnaPatel There is no a query which can work correctly on any data. Sanitize your data.

Answer (score 0):

First we need to create function which return index value of comma separated value

```
CREATE FUNCTION `SPLIT_STR`(
  x VARCHAR(255),
  delim VARCHAR(12),
  pos INT
) RETURNS varchar(255) CHARSET utf8mb3
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos),
   LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, delim, pos -1)) + 1),
   delim, '')
```

Then Create virtual recursive table from current value

```
with recursive new_table as (
  select value ,LENGTH(t.value) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.value, ',', ''))  as n ,1 as x from table t limit 1
  union all
  select value, n,1+x as x from new_table where x <= n
)
select TRIM(SPLIT_STR(value,',',x)) as value from new_table
```

will return

| value |
| --- |
| honda |
| activa |
| pleasure |
| car |